# Choosing spatial direction in Method of Lines

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Edit:The temporal variable can be set using

```
 Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines","TemporalVariable" -> t}}
```

though I couldn't find any details about how the default works.

looking through the documentation for how mathematica solves PDEs I couldn't find any information on how it decides which independent variable to treat as "time" and which it treats as "spatial" in the method of lines. Can anybody point me to this?

Comment: Can you explain in which way do you expect time variables to be treated differently than spatial variables?

Comment: Search for "TemporalVariable" (no space) in https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html

Comment: @rhermans in the method of lines all spatial variables are discretized and you solve a bunch of ODEs in the time direction.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It seems that this is indeed what I need but it has no details about how it works or how it is used (It does not seem to be an option directly in NDSolve for example).

Comment: I guess you figured it out?  It's a suboption `"MethodOfLines"` and as such has the form of an option `"TemporalVariable" -> value`. In the table in the linked docs, the default value is `Automatic` (i.e., it will try to guess).  The description says that `value` should be the time-integration variable. So indeed, something like what your edit shows, `"TemporalVariable" -> t`. (You can also search for "TemporalVariable" on this site to see example usages.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, thanks!

Comment: If you feel confused about "time" in PDE, you may want to read comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450367/is-there-any-theorem-that-tells-us-how-many-ics-or-bcs-are-needed-for-getting-th#comment970651_450367

Comment: Also, does the content in your Edit answers your question? Or you want to know the implemention details e.g. how `NDSolve` guesses out the `TemporalVariable` by default? If the former, it's better to post your Edit as an answer. If the latter, it's better to clarify the question a bit more.